# Oracle 12cR2 - After Logon Exception

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-12c, logon-trigger

Logon trigger as below:

```
create or replace TRIGGER USER3.MY_TRIGGER
AFTER LOGON
ON DATABASE
BEGIN
IF SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') IN ('USER30') THEN
IF SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'HOST') NOT IN ('HOST1', 'HOST2', 'HOST3', 'HOST4') THEN
INSERT INTO USER3.MY_TABLE (USERNAME, SID, OS_USER, HOST, IP, TERMINAL, DB_NAME, INSTANCE, INSTANCE_NAME, MODULE, SERVER_HOST, SERVICE_NAME, TIMESTAMP) VALUES
      (sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER'), sys_context('USERENV', 'SID'), sys_context('USERENV', 'OS_USER'), sys_context('USERENV', 'HOST'), sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'), sys_context('USERENV', 'TERMINAL'),
       sys_context('USERENV', 'DB_NAME'), sys_context('USERENV', 'INSTANCE'), sys_context('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME'), sys_context('USERENV','MODULE'), sys_context('USERENV','SERVER_HOST'),
       sys_context('USERENV','SERVICE_NAME'), SYSTIMESTAMP);
       COMMIT;
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Denied!  You are not allowed to logon.');
END IF;
END IF;
END;
```

Without disturbing the existing structure in any way, I want to define read only (select) permission only on its own objects (USER30) if it comes from HOST2. Can you help with this issue?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

> I want to define read only (select) permission only on its own objects (USER30) if it comes from HOST2.

This isn't MySQL.
You **cannot** grant a User different permissions based on *where* that User connects from.

A User will *always* have change permissions on their own schema.
There is **no way** around this.

This is why any Data that *matters* should live in its *own* schema[s], where it can be properly isolated from everybody else that wants to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions should be granted by Privileges.

By default every user can read **and write** his own objects. I don't think there is an easy way to prevent that. Solution would be another user account where you only `GRANT SELECT ON USER30.table_name TO USER30_RO`). Unfortunately there is no privilege in Oracle which covers all tables/view within a schema. Privilege `SELECT ANY TABLE` gives access to all tables in **all** schemas, that's not what you like to get.

Using `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'HOST')` is not secure. Depending on the driver the user can set this attribute by himself as free text.

Comment: Hello, I know all the information you have specified (HOST options is not secure and privileges, etc.). After the USER connects, it should only be able to select over its own schema. Isn't there a solution left in the corner?

Comment: E.g; an exception that will prevent the user coming from this host if they run a command other than select on their schema.

Comment: No, there is not. The owner of an object will _always_ have complete control of that object and there is no way to limit that. Ideally, in Oracle an application never connects directly to the schema that owns the application tables/objects. It connects to a separate runtime user account that has the appropriate DML privileges and no DDL privileges on the application objects.